# How to influence the filter so that it set white color for text on pink background?

Tags: html, css, background, css-filters

I need to set text color dynamically based on background (text color could be white or black). I chose filter css for that. But I don't know how to control it.  When background is `pink` I want to see my text `white`. When background is `#ffebee`I want to see text color `black`. Now for both situations text color is black.

```css
.container0 {
  background-color: red
}

.container1 {
  background-color: pink
}

.container2 {
  background-color: #ffebee;
}

.container3 {
  background-color: white
}

.filter {
  font-size: 40px;
  background: inherit;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  filter: sepia(5) saturate(100) invert(1) grayscale(1) contrast(9);
}
```

```html
<div class="container0">
  <div class="filter">
    Text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container1">
  <div class="filter">
    Text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <div class="filter">
    Text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container3">
  <div class="filter">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

desired result (it shouldn't be hardcoded, but I hope for some hack):

[image]